# Create a <div> inside a <div> and append some contents on that <div> created jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am customizing a plugin and that plugin has its own HTML structure. My problem is I want to make those contents be put in one `<div>`. I'll explain more after my code.

Here's the plugin HTML code:

```
<div class="section">
  <div class="panel">
    <h2>Test</h2>
    <div class="box">
      Content 1
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      Content 1
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      Content 1
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="panel">
    <h2>Test 2</h2>
    <div class="box">
      Content 2
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      Content 2
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      Content 2
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="panel">
    <h2>Test 3</h2>
    <div class="box">
      Content 3
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      Content 3
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      Content 3
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So here's what I want. I want those `.box` be put in one `<div>`.

Here's my desired HTML code:

```
<div class="section">
  <div class="panel">
    <h2>Test</h2>
    <div class="wrapper-box">
      <div class="box">
        Content 1
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        Content 1
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        Content 1
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="panel">
    <h2>Test 2</h2>
    <div class="wrapper-box">
      <div class="box">
        Content 2
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        Content 2
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        Content 2
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="panel">
    <h2>Test 3</h2>
    <div class="wrapper-box">
      <div class="box">
        Content 3
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        Content 3
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        Content 3
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Those `.box` elements are being wrap inside the `.wrapper-box`. How will I do that using jQuery ? I believe using `append` is good but I don't really know what to do or how to do it :) Your answers are much appreciated. Thank you Sir/Mam :)

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far and what problems/errors you have run into.  It is considered bad form to post a request for SO users to write code for you.

Answer (score 4):

You can iterate over each `.panel` and use [wrapAll()](https://api.jquery.com/wrapAll/)

```
$('.panel').each(function(){
    $(this).find('.box').wrapAll('<div class="wrapper-box" />')
});
```

```js
$('.panel').each(function() {
  $(this).find('.box').wrapAll('<div class="wrapper-box" />')
})
```

```css
.wrapper-box {
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 5px;
}
.box {
  border: 1px solid green;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="section">
  <div class="panel">
    <h2>Test</h2>

    <div class="box">Content 1</div>
    <div class="box">Content 1</div>
    <div class="box">Content 1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel">
    <h2>Test 2</h2>

    <div class="box">Content 2</div>
    <div class="box">Content 2</div>
    <div class="box">Content 2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel">
    <h2>Test 3</h2>

    <div class="box">Content 3</div>
    <div class="box">Content 3</div>
    <div class="box">Content 3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You amaze me everytime with your answers and your knowledge!! :) +1